# Compiling Columns into Single Workworksheet

Tags: vba, excel

I need to copy paired course codes and respective categories from two non-adjacent columns on several worksheets onto a single worksheet compiling all pairs.

One course may fall into three or four categories and exist on three or four worksheets and I need a unique observation for each one of these.

I have other worksheets as well, so I can't simply use something like

```
Select Case sh.Name
Case Is <> "All Course Codes"
```

Nor can I use a hard-coded range for any given worksheet, as they are all different and often changing.  The data is in columns A and D consistently, though.  I have very little knowledge of VBA, so I've cobbled together this from various sources:

```
Dim sh As Worksheet
Dim DestSh As Worksheet
Dim LastRow As Long

ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets("Course Codes").Delete

Set DestSh = ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets.Add
DestSh.Name = "Course Codes"
DestSh.Cells(1, 1).Value = "Category"
DestSh.Cells(1, 2).Value = "Course Code"

For Each sh In ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets
    Select Case sh.Name
    Case "Category1", "Category2", "Category3", "Category4", "Category5", "Category6"

        FinalRow = Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row
        ThisValue = Cells(x, 4).Value
        NextRow = Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row + 1

        For x = 2 To FinalRow
            If ThisValue <> "" Then
            Cells(x, 1).Copy
            Destination DestSh.Cells(NextRow, 1).Select
            End If
        Next
    End Select
Next
End Sub
```

To explain, I am attempting to select each sheet by name, then run down column D and copy the data from A and D to columns A and B on the new sheet as long as there is a value in D on the data sheet.

Once it runs out of values, it would progress onto the next sheet, appending the new copies to the bottom of the list on the "Course Codes" compilation sheet.

The macro runs, creates the new sheet, and titles the columns correctly.  It does not copy any of the desired information into this new sheet, however.  What mistake am I making here?

Thank you in advance for your help, and let me know if there is any information I am missing to get an accurate answer.

Comment: There are a few issues with your code: 1. You are using x without an initial value (ThisValue = Cells(x, 4).Value) 2. NextRow should be "FinalRow + 1" instead of finding the last row again 3. It's not pasting the data: just copy, then select destination range

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This will append data from Col A & D on all Sheets, to a new "Course Codes" sheet, Col A & B

---

```
Option Explicit

Sub getData()

    Const OFFSET        As Byte = 2
    Const COL1_NAME     As String = "Category"
    Const COL2_NAME     As String = "Course Codes"
    Const SHEET_NAMES   As String = "Category1,Category2,Category3,Category4,Category5,Category6"

    Dim thisWS  As Worksheet
    Dim destWS  As Worksheet
    Dim last1   As Long
    Dim last2   As Long
    Dim rng     As Range

    Application.DisplayAlerts = False   'turn off sheet deletion warning
    Application.ScreenUpdating = False  'turn off display

    For Each thisWS In ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets    'look for sheet "Course Codes"
        If thisWS.Name = COL2_NAME Then
            thisWS.Delete                           'if found, delete it
            Exit For
        End If
    Next
    Set destWS = Worksheets.Add(Sheets(1))          'create a new sheet "Course Codes"
    With destWS
        .Name = COL2_NAME
        .Cells(1, 1).Value = COL1_NAME              'add header "Category"
        .Cells(1, 2).Value = COL2_NAME              'add header "Course Codes"
        With .UsedRange.Rows(1)
            .HorizontalAlignment = xlCenter         'header alignment: center
            .Font.Bold = True                       'header font: bold
            .Interior.Color = RGB(222, 222, 222)    'header cell background: grey
        End With
    End With

    last2 = OFFSET                                  'first row on "Course Codes"

    For Each thisWS In ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets    'check all sheets if in SHEET_NAMES

        If InStr(1, SHEET_NAMES, thisWS.Name, vbBinaryCompare) > 0 Then

            last1 = thisWS.UsedRange.Rows.Count     'last row of current sheet

            If last1 > OFFSET Then                  'if the sheet has more than 2 rows

               'Col A - Destination sheet: destWS.Cells(Row, Col)
                Set rng = destWS.Range( _
                                        destWS.Cells(last2, 1), _
                                        destWS.Cells(last1 + last2 - OFFSET, 1))

                rng.Value = thisWS.Range("A2:" & "A" & last1).Value  'copy Col A to A

               'Col B - Destination sheet: destWS.Cells(Row, Col)
                Set rng = destWS.Range( _
                                        destWS.Cells(last2, 2), _
                                        destWS.Cells(last1 + last2 - OFFSET, 2))

                rng.Value = thisWS.Range("D2:" & "D" & last1).Value  'copy Col D to B

                last2 = last2 + last1 - 1   'increment offset by (total copied rows - 1)
            End If
        End If
    Next
    destWS.UsedRange.Columns.AutoFit        'resize columns to fit the widest text
    Application.DisplayAlerts = True
    Application.ScreenUpdating = True
End Sub
```

---

[image: Compiling Columns]

Comment: Thank you for this, it's a great start.  However, I'm running into a bug and my rudimentary VBA skills aren't enough for me to figure out where it's coming from.  When I run the script, it creates the new sheet with formatted titles correctly.  However, it pulls only the first sheet from the case argument instead of working on all the named sheets, and inserts the data from Col A on the original sheet into _both_ Cols A and B on the Course Code sheet.  I think it might have something to do with the ranges but the syntax you gave me is a bit beyond my skill level.  Any insight?  Thanks again.

Comment: I am extracting from a subset of all sheets.  Thank you immensely for your help, I've learned more about VBA from this problem than I have in all my basic macro-writing.

Comment: I think the issue is arising because I am trying to pull the data from tables on these sheets.  What do you think?

Comment: I improved my test file and fixed the issues you mentioned (tables don't affect data extraction - I just converted my 3 test sheets to tables and it works the same). I also added more comments describing the steps

Comment: I tweaked a couple things here and there - was getting a bunch of extra rows and some error values (no idea from where, couldn't find them in any table) but those are easy to trim off.  This looks great!  Thank you Paul!

Comment: To keep the code short I used an inaccurate way of determining the last row: the "UsedRange" method returns rows and columns with hidden or invisible data (like font formatting, row height, empty formulas, etc). To get the last row with data in column A, you could update the line **`last1 = thisWS.UsedRange.Rows.Count`** to this **`last1 = thisWS.Cells(thisWS.Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row`** (fully qualified)